# Write a function that returns the list of unique data types

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I am getting no result when I run the following code. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the "t =" line. P.s it has to be using a while loop.

```
def get_data_types(it):
    result = []
    while True:
        try:
            t = type(it)
            if not t in result:
                result.append(t) 
        except:
            break
    return result

# Main program (do not change):
print(get_data_types(iter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])))
print(get_data_types(iter([1, 2, 3, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])))
print(get_data_types(iter([True, (7,), [8], {9: 10}])))
```

what I expect to get:

```
class 'str'
class 'int', class 'float'
class 'bool', <class 'tuple', class 'list', class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the type of the iterator rather than the type of the elements in the underlying iterable.  Use the iterator you are given to drive the loop and that build your list of unique element types.

```
def get_data_types(it):
    type_list = []
    for element in it:
        if type(element) not in type_list:
            type_list.append(type(element))
    return type_list

# Main program (do not change):
print(get_data_types(iter(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])))
print(get_data_types(iter([1, 2, 3, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])))
print(get_data_types(iter([True, (7,), [8], {9: 10}])))
```

Output:

```
[<class 'str'>]
[<class 'int'>, <class 'float'>]
[<class 'bool'>, <class 'tuple'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'dict'>]
```